# Hook for Laravel component?

Tags: laravel

Is there a hook that can hack into the Laravel component?

For example:

in `components/foo.blade.php`:

```
<div>Foo</div>
```

in any view:

```
<x-foo />
```

output:

```
<div>Hi Foo</div>
<div>Foo</div>
```

which insert a `<div>Hi Foo</div>` automatically.

I don't want to use a custom blade directive to do that, because I want to get the `<div>Hi Foo</div>` inserted in every component.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHtml($post->body);
    $divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

/** Get the lengths of the div to perform element replacing */

$divLength = $divs->length;

for ($i = 0; $i < $divLength; $i++) {
    $elem=$divs->item(0);

// print innerHTML
$get = $elem->innerHTML; // '<p>foo</p>'

// set innerHTML
$elem->innerHTML = '<p>hi</p>'.$get;

// print document (with our changes)
echo $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

in controller u cAN USE DOM  may b this will help you